# Error in posting form in Magento Module?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I am new to `Magento` and i am given the task to create an extension.

I am reading over the articles and moving forward.

So far I am able to add my menu in main navigation in admin section and on that menu i am calling a `Controller` and loading a `View` of my `.phtml` file.

Now i have a form on my `.phtml` file which i am posting on the same controller but on different function but instead of calling that function it is going to dashboard. I have checked the form action, it is perfect but still not calling that function.

Below is the code of my `Controller`.

```
class Gwb_Magecrmsync_Adminhtml_CustomersController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
         ->_setActiveMenu('menu1')
         ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Synchronize Data'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Synchronize Data'))
         ->_title($this->__('Synchronize Data'));

    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
        'my_block_name_here',
        array('template' => 'magecrmsync/customers.phtml')
    );
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

    $this->renderLayout();

}

public function authenticationAction()
{
    if($this->getRequest()->getPost())
    {
        try
        {
            $username = $this->getRequest()->getPost('username');
            $password = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');

        // validate user here
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "NO";
    }
    //$this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

}

Below is my `customers.phtml` file code:

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('*/*/authentication'); ?>" method="post">
  <fieldset>
<ul>
 <li>
   <label for="username">Username</label>
   <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
 </li>
 <li>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
</li>
 <li>
    <input type="submit" name="authenticate" id="authenticate" value="Authenticate" />
</li>
  </ul>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Any help would be very much appreciated and will be helpful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a secret key to the form for security, or it won't work. Add this into your form and it should work :)

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

Comment: Hello Andrew, when i am putting this hidden field into the form, the value is blank, it is not getting form key. Can you tell me why?

Comment: take a look at this: http://www.spinonesolutions.com/2011/01/admin-form-post-form_key/

Comment: I just saw that, but i don't understand why in my form, key is blank?

Comment: Is there any alternative of getting form key?

Comment: The difference between my code and spinonesolutions.com code is that their controller is extending Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template and my controller is extending Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action. Can this make the difference in fetching form key?

Comment: notice that's not a controller, they have a controller and a block, they are different things altogether.

Comment: But i m just doing it with controller and my .phtml file, can i get form key in this case?

Comment: Ok, i got the form key using : <?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>